# How to be notified when an edit box has been updated

Tags: vb6, event-handling

In a VB6 project, I would like to be notified when an edit control (text field) has been updated (i.e. : character string has been added by a user into the text field).

I did not find any documentation on the different events which can be catched for an edit MFC control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry... what does MFC have to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the [`_Change` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445411%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). However, I personally do not like this event since it is notoriously unreliable.

```
Private Sub txtYourTextFieldControl_Change()
    ' some code here
End Sub
```

*** edit ***
We are talking about VB6 textbox, correct? I am not sure what MFC has to do with this.

Comment: Then its a `_Change` event for the text box.